# How can I check the value of a Fluid Contact type?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I want to retrieve data from a fluid contact set only if the contact is from a certain type.

 
This is what i wrote:

```
ContactSet fcset = FcSetGridBox.Tag as ContactSet; 
foreach (Contact fc in fcset.Contacts) 
{ 
    if (fc.ContactType.Equals(oilwater)) 
    { 
        args.OilZoneContV=fc.GetZValue(); 
    } 
    else 
    if (fc.ContactType = "oilgas"') 
    { 
        args.GasZoneContV = fc.GetZValue(); 
    } 
}
```

But I don't know what to compare the ContactType to. 
The Ocean manual mention the contact type enumeration but i cant use them as string

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer: I need to test against the actual enumeration values.

```
if (fc.ContactType.Equals(ContactType.OilGas))
{ ... }
```

And Enumerations can safely be compared with the == operator as well.